# How to generate D3.js circular dendrogram code from Python

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js, plot

The following figure is generated with D3.js.

[image]

based on the code [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339607):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Flare Dendrogram</title>
<style>

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var radius = 960 / 2;

var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
    .size([360, radius - 120]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal.radial()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x / 180 * Math.PI]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", radius * 2)
    .attr("height", radius * 2)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");

d3.json("/d/4063550/flare.json", function(error, root) {
  var nodes = cluster.nodes(root);

  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(cluster.links(nodes))
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")"; })

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5);

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".31em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end"; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "translate(8)" : "rotate(180)translate(-8)"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
});

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", radius * 2 + "px");

</script>
```

Is there a way I can use Python to generate the above exact figure (HTML)?

Comment: Of course there's a way -- you just have to re-write all the relevant portions of the d3.js library and the DOM in python -- but that's probably not what you want to hear.  Can you explain more clearly *why* you want to use python instead of Javascript?  Perhaps there is an alternative approach that could satisfy your objectives without reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want to avoid having to write javascript and using python instead, you could have a look at pyjs. From their [website](http://pyjs.org/):

> ```
> pyjs contains a Python-to-JavaScript compiler, an AJAX framework and a 
> Widget Set API. pyjs started life as a Python port of Google Web Toolkit, 
> the Java-to-JavaScript compiler.
> ```

I haven't used it and am unsure how you would go about including the d3 library. However their wiki has the following page:

https://github.com/pyjs/pyjs/wiki/Calling-a-jQuery-component-from-Pyjs

That article might give you an idea of whether pyjs is useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way I can use Python to generate the above exact figure (HTML)?

Not too dissimilar to [pandita's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24583763/977931), you  could use [Brython](http://www.brython.info/), which allows you to run Python in a web browser. Some sample skeleton code (using D3.js; I don't know of any Python libraries that give you a dendogram result as good as D3.js.):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Flare Dendrogram</title>
<style>
/* CSS goes here */
</style>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="brython.js"></script>
<script type="text/python">
# 
# Python code to generate dendogram here 
# (equivalent to the sample JavaScript code provided) 
#
</script>


<body onload="brython()">
</body>
</html>
```

But this doesn't seem like a great solution.

You may also find this StackOverflow page helpful: [How do I create a radial cluster like the following code-example in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089030/how-do-i-create-a-radial-cluster-like-the-following-code-example-in-python)